# Custom Editor Drag & Drop, how to update the variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a custom editor script that shows variables, mainly with a different name than their variable names.  I am making a vehicle drivetrain script and I'd like to be able to drop all of the wheels into a drag and drop box which would then update the wheels.

I took this example: https://gist.github.com/bzgeb/3800350 and tried to modify it.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(CleanerAxleSettings))]
public class CleanerAxleSetupInspector : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty axle;
    private SerializedObject obj;
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        axle = serializedObject.FindProperty("axle");
        obj = new SerializedObject(target);
    }
    
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(axle, new GUIContent("TEMPORARY Axle View"));
        DropAreaGUI();
        
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
    
    public void DropAreaGUI ()
    {
        Event evt = Event.current;
        Rect drop_area = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect (0.0f, 50.0f, GUILayout.ExpandWidth (true));
        GUI.Box (drop_area, "Drop Wheels Here");
     
        switch (evt.type) {
            case EventType.DragUpdated:
            case EventType.DragPerform:
                if (!drop_area.Contains (evt.mousePosition))
                    return;
             
                DragAndDrop.visualMode = DragAndDropVisualMode.Copy;
         
                if (evt.type == EventType.DragPerform) {
                    DragAndDrop.AcceptDrag ();
             
                    foreach (GameObject dragged_object in DragAndDrop.objectReferences) {
                        // Do On Drag Stuff here
                        Debug.Log(dragged_object.name);
                        AddWheel(dragged_object);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void AddWheel(GameObject mesh)
    {
        CleanerAxleSettings axleSettings = target as CleanerAxleSettings;
        Debug.Log(axleSettings.axle.wheels.Count);
        if (axleSettings.axle.wheels != null)
        {
            bool exists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < axleSettings.axle.wheels.Count; i++)
            {
                if (axleSettings.axle.wheels[i].mesh == mesh)
                {
                    exists = true;
                    i = axleSettings.axle.wheels.Count;
                
            }

            if (!exists)
            {
                // Debug.Log("Wheel doesn't exist, add it");
                // CleanerAxleSettings.Wheel wheel = new CleanerAxleSettings.Wheel();
                // // wheel.mesh = mesh;
                // axleSettings.axle.wheels.Add(wheel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // axleSettings.axle.wheels = new List<CleanerAxleSettings.Wheel>();
            // CleanerAxleSettings.Wheel wheel = new CleanerAxleSettings.Wheel();
            // wheel.mesh = mesh;
            // axleSettings.axle.wheels.Add(wheel);
        }
    }
}
```

`axle` is a using the class Axle from the target. `axle` contains a list called `wheels` which is a List of `Wheel`s which is another class that has wheel properties.

I'm pretty sure I need to use `obj` to access the current axle, but I'm unsure as to how to access the `axle.wheels` list, let alone change it from the `obj`.

Comment: at first glance the `obj` is completely redundant ... `serializedObject` already **IS** a `SerializedObject` of the current `target` ;)


Then whenever dealing with editor scripts avoid ever touching the `target` at all. If you do that you enter the dark world of handling all dirty marking and undo/redo etc yourself!

Rather stick to going through the `SerializedProperties` and further `SerializedObject`s for `UnityEngine.Objetc` references ... it's a bit hard without seeing your `CleanerAxleSettings` (and related types)